# How does this strange 32-bit/64-bit interop solution work?

Tags: windows, com, interop, com-interop, dcom

I'm currently maintaining a piece of software that we outsourced couple of years ago and that is poorly documented. The piece is a COM server for consuming by third-party applications and an installer that does all necessary deployment.

There's the core compiled as 32-bit DLL and meant to be used from 32-bit applications. And there's also a shim compiled as 64-bit DLL and intended for being used from 64-bit applications. The shim calls CoCreateInstance() to instantiate the core and redirects the calls to the core. The core depends on a huge set of other 32-bit libraries.

The 32-bit core is registered exactly as an in-proc server normally would - there's an entry under HKCR\CLSID that includes the core class id and the path to the library under InprocServer32. The 64-bit shim is registered the same way and also an Application Id is introduced for the 64-bit shim - it is added under HKCR\CLSID and also registered with DCOM - there's an entry in the DCOM console with that Application Id.

Now the DCOM registration looks strange. Why would the shim be registered to DCOM and not the core? I expect that the 32-bit  core should be registered to DCOM to be instantiated in a separate process and shielded from the 64-bit consumer. But apparently it works as it is currently done. What's the sence in registering the 64-bit shim and not the 32-bit core with DCOM?

Comment: I dont know if its relevent to understanding this, but don't forget that 32bit apps and 64bit apps get different views of the registry.
Using reflection, when a 32bit app tries to open HKCR\..., it actually opens HKCR\Wow6432Node\...
So the registration information used by 32bit apps is under HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{clsid}, and for 64bit apps its under HKCR\CLSID\{clsid} (using a 64bit registry viewer of course).

Comment: The changes I described in the question are in both branches.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that you can mix-and-match 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs and processes. The 32-bit core in this case doesn't use DCOM because it can be loaded directly into a host 32-bit process. The 64-bit shim requires DCOM because the developers of it are taking advantage of COM's ability to host the core in a separate process, even on the same machine. That's required since the 32-bit core can't be loaded into a 64-bit host. Using DCOM marshalls all the calls to and from the core, sitting in a separate 32-bit process. It's an optimal arrangement, since calling to the core doesn't then go over DCOM. The developers very likely took advantage of this in their testing, debugging in a 32-bit process, without DCOM getting in the way, until the core was proven to work well enough to try calling it from a 64-bit application.

Comment: I still don't get this completely. When COM+ is used for the same purpose the 32-bit component is usually put into a COM+ application. Then the 64-bit consumer calls CoCreateInstance(), the call is routed trough COM+, COM+ starts a 32-bit surrogate process, loads the component there, fires up marshalling and it all works. With COM+ the consumer is 64-bit and the 32-bit component is put into a COM+ application.

Comment: Now why is it different here? As I get it the 64-bit consumer will call CoCreateInstance(), the 64-bit process will be started under DCOM in another separate process. But how will the latter load the 32-bit core - the core is not under DCOM. That's what I really don't get.